# LINQ to identify a row that is the first in consecutive occurrences that meet criteria

Tags: linq

Let's say this table stores the high temperature for each day

```
date        high temperature
====        ===========    
5/15        98
5/14        97
5/13        92
5/12        82
5/11        93
5/10        91
5/9         88
```

If the most recent date is above 90, I want the earliest date of consecutive occurrences of above 90.  In the dataset above, 5/13 is what I want.

What I have tried

```
var consecutives = records.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Date).TakeWhile(i=>i.Temperature > 90);
var earliest = consecutives.Min(i=>i.Date);
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: what primary key are you using in your records?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the latest item after `TakeWhile`:

```
var earliset = records
   .OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
   .TakeWhile(i => i.Temperature  > 90)
   .LastOrDefault();
```

If the most recent row has a temperature below 90 then null will be returned.